# Adding data into the database with django by pressing enter

Tags: html, django, enter

I do not see what I am doing wrong when trying to add data into the database. When I am pressing the button Submit, nothing is entered in the database. The same happens when pressing the key enter.

Here is my html file.

```js
<script>
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
      alert('enter key is pressed');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <p>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" value="{{post.id}}" />
      <div class="col-xs-16" style="margin: 0; 0;padding: 3%;">
        <label for="inputsm">Oracle</label>
        <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" value="{{ post }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none" /> {{ form.body }}
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the views.py

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'posts':posts,
        'cat':category,
    }
    return render(request, 'journal/post_list.html', context)

def add_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_details', pk=post.pk)
            return render(request, 'journal/post_list.html', {'post': post})

    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render_to_response('journal/post_list.html', context)
```

Comment: `post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)` what is pk? where does that come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the form get submitted? If not, maybe try adding some javascript to submit the form, when the key is pressed

```
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: When adding this code, this is getting better. The data is being entered in the database. However, I still doing something wrong because the data is not displayed. It's displayed as a dash. Thanks for making this advance.